# Openpyxl corrupts Excel workbook after saving with modified external link

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am encountering an issue with openpyxl that appears to be causing corruption in my Excel workbooks. I'm using openpyxl version 3.0.10.

Here is a general outline of my code:

```
import openpyxl
import glob
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from openpyxl import __version__

# function to get existing data sources in a workbook
def get_existing_data_sources(file_path):
    
    # Set data sources
    data_sources = {}

    # Try getting external links
    try:
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
        items = workbook._external_links

        # Iterate through list and extract url
        for index, item in enumerate(items):

            # reformat link string
            Mystr = workbook._external_links[index].file_link.Target
            Mystr = Mystr.replace("file:///","")

            # update key-pair
            data_sources[index] = Mystr.replace("%20"," ")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while extracting data sources: {str(e)}")

    # return statement
    return(data_sources, workbook)


# Function to modify the existing data sources in the workbook
def modify_data_source_links(data_sources, workbook):
    try:
        # Flag false
        modified = False
        
        # get workbook external links (unformatted links)
        items = workbook._external_links

        # Copy data sources to have them relinked
        modified_data_sources = data_sources.copy()

        # Correct data sources to new pattern
        for i in modified_data_sources:
            modified_data_sources[i] = modified_data_sources[i].replace('<OLD LINK>','<NEW LINK>')

        # Enumerate through external links and replace values based on the link index in the cell
        for index, item in enumerate(items):
            link_str = data_sources.get(index)

            if link_str:
                # Reformat the new link string
                new_link = modified_data_sources[index]

                # Reformat newlink (make spaces to %20)
                new_link = new_link.replace(" ","%20")

                # Replace link target
                workbook._external_links[index].file_link.Target = new_link

                # flag modified as true
                modified = True
                
        if modified:
            print("Data source links modified successfully.")
        else:
            print("No data source links matching the old data source found.")
    
    # Return Error
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # Path to the workbook
    path = askdirectory(title='Select Folder') # shows dialog box and return the path
    print(path)  
    excel_file_paths = glob.glob('{}/*.xlsx'.format(path), recursive = True)
    
    # Process each file
    for excel_file_path in excel_file_paths:
        
        # get existing data sources
        existing_data_sources, workbook = get_existing_data_sources(excel_file_path)

        # if data sources do not exist, prompt message
        if not existing_data_sources:
            print("No data source links found in the workbook. Moving on...")
            
        # else relink the data sources
        else:
            print("Existing data source links:")
            for i, data_source in enumerate(existing_data_sources, 1):
                print(f"{i}. {data_source}")

            modify_data_source_links(existing_data_sources, workbook)
            
            # Save workbook
            excel_file_path = excel_file_path.replace('\\','/')
            workbook.save(excel_file_path)
            workbook.close()
    
            print('Modified the links in: {}, moving on...'.format(excel_file_path))

    print('Script completed!')
```

The code runs without raising any errors, and the workbook is successfully generated. However, when I try to pen the workbook, excel displays an error message stating the file is corrupted and prompts for recovery. Has anyone else encountered this issue with openpyxl when working with external links in Excel workbooks? Am I missing something in my code or is there a workaround to prevent workbook corruption when modifying external links using openpyxl? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you described what your code is attempting. Sure the title gives an idea and I have some idea from your previous question, but a summary of what the code is doing always helps.  In the line `modified_data_sources[i].replace('<OLD LINK>','<NEW LINK>')` how/where are you extracting the *OLD LINK* ? or is `'<OLD LINK>'` the actual text you are replacing? Presumably this is where your causing problems with the workbook since its the only section that actually makes a change. `Some debugging here should help, even just printing what the New link is after it's changed.`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way:**
workbook = load_workbook(filename= file_path,data_only=True,**keep_links=False**)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Oz, your code works for me. The saved files with the modified external links are not corrupted.
I only made a little change, to apply to subforlders I modified this line: "excel_file_paths = glob.glob('{}/**/*.xlsx'.format(path), recursive = True)".
Thanks